# Returning different constrained types using generics in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I would like to define a function, that give some parameters returns a specific implementation of a `UITableViewCell` like so:

```
func cellClassFromCellType<T: UITableViewCell>(cellType: CellType, atIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> T.Type {
    switch cellType
    case someEnum: return NotificationCell
    default: return UITableViewCell
}
```

so that I could do something like this:

```
let cellType = cellClassFromCellType(.Test, atIndexPath: NSIndexPath())
let cell = cellType(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "")
```

But with the above implementation I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'NotificationCell.Type' to return type 'T.Type'
```

I'm not even sure that the above implementation is in the right direction, so any input will be helpful.

---

Preferably I would like to define this function in a `protocol` as well, so some help with defining such a protocol would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

Swift is a statically typed language, so all types must be fixed at compile time. A function can't dynamically shift from returning one type to another based on factors determined at runtime. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725803/how-to-use-generic-protocol-as-a-variable-type)

Since you've asked about protocols, Swift does not support generic parameterised protocols (yet), but you could read [here](http://milen.me/writings/swift-generic-protocols/) about possible workaround.