# Swift associated types and protocol inheritance

Tags: swift, mvvm, protocols, associated-types

I'm using Swift 2.2 and I declared a protocol with associated type as follow:

```
protocol CollectionViewModeling {
    associatedtype CellType
    func cellAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CellType
}
```

Now I have a view model protocol conform to the above protocol :

```
enum MyItemCell {
    case MyItemCell1, MyItemCell2
}
protocol ItemsListViewModeling: CollectionViewModeling {
    associatedtype CellType = MyCell
}
```

Finally, somewhere else, I want to declare a var that is conform to le protocol ItemsListViewModeling :

```
var viewModel: ItemsListViewModeling
```

And I'm getting this error :

> Protocol 'ItemsListViewModeling' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

But I can easily create a class that implements this protocol.

Is it possible to declare a var to an associated typed protocol ? As I'm giving the final type of the associated type in the protocol ItemsListViewModeling, I don't understand why am I seeing this error from the compiler.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See there [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725803/how-to-use-generic-protocol-as-a-variable-type)

> You can't treat protocols with associated types like regular protocols
>   and declare them as standalone variable types.