# Assigning a Nested Associated type Protocol to a variable results in error

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols, composition

When we assign an associated type protocol to another protocol's property as its type we end in error. From below example we can see that type associated property A is assigned as type property to Bigger Protocol's variable.

The requirement is that the associated type needs to be dynamic and is to be controlled by the struct/class implementing the Bigger Protocol. In the below example the Table struct needs to determine the DataType associated property and should cascade to Protocol A and Protocol B.

The DataType may or may not be same for Protocol A and Protocol B.

Update: The answer is
[Swift associated types and protocol inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452303/swift-associated-types-and-protocol-inheritance)

All of the posts explain how to implement a protocol with associated type. What I am looking for here is how to have protocol within a protocol using associated type at the inner most level.

```swift
protocol ProtocolA {
    associatedtype DataTypeA
    var variableA: DataTypeA { get set }
}

protocol ProtocolB {
    associatedtype DataTypeB
    var variableB: DataTypeB { get set }
    var variableC: DataTypeB { get set }
}


protocol BiggerProtocol {
    var biggerVariableA: ProtocolA? { get set } //Protocol 'ProtocolA' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
    var biggerVariableB: ProtocolB? { get set } //Protocol 'ProtocolB' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
}

struct Table: BiggerProtocol {
    var biggerVariableA: ProtocolA? //Same Error
    var biggerVariableB: ProtocolB? //Same Error
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @ArikSegal Protocol 'ProtocolA' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements