# Collections of Protocol Types - protocol oriented programming

Tags: swift, collections, protocols, identifiable

I want a collection of a protocol type: in this case I want a variable "**party**" to be an array of type GameCharacter so I can put all things that conform to GameCharacter inside it.

the code below produces the following error:

> Protocol 'GameCharacter' can only be used as a generic constraint because
> it has Self or associated type requirements

what's the problem here? how to do it right?

```
protocol GameCharacter: Identifiable {
    var name: String {get}
    var maxHealt: Int {get}
    var healt: Int { get set }

    }

struct Warrior: GameCharacter, Fighter {
    var name: String
    var maxHealt: Int
    var healt: Int
    var armor: Armor
    var weapon: Weapon
    var resistence: Int
    var id: String {
        return name
    }
}

var party: [GameCharacter] <--- error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not inherit your protocol from `Identifiable` (which has generics) in this case, instead add `id` explicitly and then below (simplified) is compilable

```
protocol GameCharacter {
    var id: String { get }     // << here !!
    var name: String {get}
    var maxHealt: Int {get}
    var healt: Int { get set }
    
}

struct Warrior: GameCharacter {
    var name: String
    var maxHealt: Int
    var healt: Int
    var resistence: Int
    var id: String {        // << here !!
        return name
    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain why i should not inherit from Identifiable?

Comment: Because Identifiable has generics inside, so your protocol also became generics and protocols with generics are not allowed to be used in variable declarations as you want to do - that's why you got the error. If you want use your protocol in array then don't make it generics.

Comment: Ok thanks, but with your solution - GameCharacter protocol not conforming to Identifiable - I'm not able to use the "party"-Array (of type Character) inside a ForEach like intended.. but ok I can of cause use id:\.name key path..

Comment: You are able to use directly any property in ForEach as identifier, in your case it can be as `ForEach(party, id: \.id)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Identifiable` is a protocol with associated type. Unfortunately, Swift does not support what you are trying to achieve, **yet**.

Please refer [Swift associated types and protocol inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452303/swift-associated-types-and-protocol-inheritance) and [How to use generic protocol as a variable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725803/how-to-use-generic-protocol-as-a-variable-type) for discussions around this topic. These links discuss on possible solutions as well.