# Use generic protocols as variable type

Tags: swift

I would like to create a generic protocol for a data fetching service like this:

```
protocol FetchDataDelegate: AnyObject {

    associatedtype ResultData

    func didStartFetchingData()
    func didFinishFetchingData(with data: ResultData)
    func didFinishFetchingData(with error: Error)
}

class Controller: UIViewController, FetchDataDelegate {

    func didStartFetchingData() {
        //...
    }

    func didFinishFetchingData(with data: ResultData) {
        //...
    }

    func didFinishFetchingData(with error: Error) {
        //...
    }
}

class NetworkManager {

    weak var delegate: FetchDataDelegate?
    //...
}
```

The Controller class would have a reference to a NetworkManager instance, and through this, I would like to start the network operations. When the operation is ended I would like to call the appropriate delegate function to pass the result back to the controller. But with this setup I got the following error:
**Protocol 'FetchDataDelegate' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements**
The question is what should I do to use this generic protocol as a variable type? Or if is not possible what would be the correct way? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use generic protocol as a variable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725803/how-to-use-generic-protocol-as-a-variable-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is closely related to the [question David Smith linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725803/how-to-use-generic-protocol-as-a-variable-type) (and you should read that as well), it's worth answering separately because it's a different concrete use case, and so we can talk about it.

First, imagine you *could* store this variable. What would you do with it? What function in `NetworkManager` could call `delegate.didFinishFetchingData`? How would you generate the `ResultData` when you don't know what it is?

The point is that this isn't what PATs (protocols with associated types) are for. It's not their goal. Their goal is to help you add extensions to other types, or to restrict which kinds of types can be passed to generic algorithms. For those purposes, they're incredibly powerful. But what you want are generics, not protocols.

Instead of creating delegates, you should use generic functions to handle the result of a specific call, rather than trying to nail down each view controller to a specific result type (which isn't very flexible anyway). For example, in the simplest, and least flexible way that still gives you progress reporting:

```
struct APIClient {
    func fetch<Model: Decodable>(_: Model.Type,
                                 with urlRequest: URLRequest,
                                 completion: @escaping (Result<Model, Error>) -> Void)
    -> Progress {

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, _, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
            else if let data = data {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                completion(Result {
                    try decoder.decode(Model.self, from: data)
                })
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        return task.progress
    }
}

let progress = APIClient().fetch(User.self, with: urlRequest) { user in ... }
```

This structure is the basic approach to this entire class of problem. [It can be made much, much more flexible depending on your specific needs.](https://gist.github.com/rnapier/54ea4a0faa8f987d9ca452b354366296)

(If your `didStartFetchingData` method is very important, in ways that `Progress` doesn't solve, leave a comment and I'll show how to implement that kind of thing. It's not difficult, but this answer is pretty long already.)

Comment: You are right I was thinking about that maybe every controller should have a different network manager so in those classes I would know that which concrete type belongs to which class.
Thank you for your answer, it helped me to understand the problem much more. Before you answered I got this "solution": create a base protocol which contains the start and the error method, and every controller has an own protocol which extends this base protocol with the function that is missing, of course with the concrete parameter type.
Now I see that your approach is much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725803/how-to-use-generic-protocol-as-a-variable-type)

In summary, you cannot use generic protocols as variable types, it would have to be leveraged as a generic constraint since you wouldn't know the type of `ResultData` at compilation time